# How to translate sentences to predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Here are the sentences I worked on, I am unsure of my formulations and was wondering if I can get some feedback.

Unicorns do not exist.

$\forall x, \neg unicorn(x)$

Every professional tennis player could beat any amateur tennis player.

$\forall x \forall y (professional(x) \land amateur(y) \rightarrow beat(x,y) ) $

Comment: Great! They are perfect.

Comment: To reduce ambiguity, write $\forall x \forall y ((professional(x) \land amateur (y)) \to beat(x,y))$. You should also specify that "$beat(x,y)$" means $x$ beats $y$, even if it is obvious by context and intuition.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!